# Получить ответы от кнопок в Telegram-боте

Tags: python, flask, webhook

Я хочу получить ответ, какая кнопка нажата. Не могу понять в чем дело. Бот на веб-хостинге Бегет.  Простые сообщения приходят и другие команды обрабатываются нормально.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request
from flask import Response
import requests


TOKEN = "***"

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../public_html")


def tel_parse_message(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        txt = message["message"]["text"]

        return chat_id, txt
    except:
        return "NO text found-->>"
    
def tel_parse_buttons(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message["callback_query"]["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        response_data = message["callback_query"]["data"]

        return chat_id, response_data
    except:
        return "NO text found-->>"


def tel_send_message(chat_id, text):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage"
    payload = {"chat_id": chat_id, "text": text}

    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)

    return r

def tel_send_calc(chat_id):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage"

    payload = {
        "chat_id": chat_id,
        "text": "Что сделать с числом?",
            'reply_markup': {
            "inline_keyboard": [
                [
                    {"text": "Прибавить", "callback_data": "+"},
                    {"text": "Вычесть", "callback_data": "-"}
                ],
                [
                    {"text": "Умножить", "callback_data": "*"},
                    {"text": "Разделить", "callback_data": "/"}
                ]
            ]
        }
    }

    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    return r


def tel_send_image(chat_id):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendPhoto"
    payload = {
        "chat_id": chat_id,
        "photo": "https://qmex.ru/image/catalog/mexlogo.png",
        "caption": "Тех Мех корпорейшен продакшен.\nЖми /go для продолжения.",
    }

    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    return r


def tel_send_go_answer(chat_id):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage"

    payload = {
        "chat_id": chat_id,
        "text": "Этот бот умеет делать вид, что он калькулятор.\nДля начала отправь мне любое число или команду /calc",
    }

    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    return r


@app.route("/***/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        msg = request.get_json()
        
        try:
            chat_id, txt = tel_parse_message(msg)

                
                           
            if txt == "/start":
                tel_send_image(chat_id)
            elif txt == "/go":
                tel_send_go_answer(chat_id)
            elif txt == "/calc":
                tel_send_calc(chat_id)
                chat_id, response_data = tel_parse_buttons(msg)
                tel_send_message(chat_id, response_data)
            else:
                tel_send_message(chat_id, "Думаю ты так не думаешь")                
            
        except:
            print("from index-->")        

        return Response("ok", status=200)
    else:
        return "<h1>Это страница-webhook для бота на Python, размещенного на хостинге Beget.</h1>"


@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def catch_all(path):
    return render_template("home.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```